# My wi-fi connection is not allowing google search. How to make it possible?

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, google-search

Got a new wi-fi router (DLink) couple of days ago, and connecting to net thru it. When I try to search (at google), it is showing “unable to connect to proxy server”? Why this is happening, how to make the search possible?

I use chrome browser.

Tried ask.com, successful. Seems only google search has the problem.

Comment: do the other web sites work? Is this solution applicable to you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmapUgg12UU

Comment: Can open sites. Watched your video. (In my machine) at LAN settings > use proxy server box is already unchecked...

Comment: the video also explains further that you have to boot into safe mode and do a regedit. Tried that?

Comment: Digging that slow groove.

Comment: No. Will do that... @Prasanna

Comment: Deleted 'proxy enable'. Now is able to do search. Thanks.